# Approximating $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} e^{-wj} = 1/w +1/2 +w/12 -w^3 /720 +w^5/30240 +...$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

So I know that $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} e^{-wj} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-w}},\quad \text{if}\quad e^{-w} <1,$$ and that 
$$e^{-w} = 1-w+w^2/2 -w^3/6 +w^4/24,$$ but don't see a way to combine the two results to give the approximation on the title.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One has
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-e^{-w}}&=\frac1{w-w^2/2+w^3/6-w^4/24}
\\\\&=\frac1{w}\cdot\frac1{1-w/2+w^2/6-w^3/24}
\end{align}
$$ then one may set $u=-w/2+w^2/6-w^3/24 $ and, as $w \to 0$, one may use, 
$$
\frac1{1+u}=1-u+u^2-u^3+u^5+O(u^6)
$$ as $u \to 0$.

One gets the announced result.